# Semidivisibility

Tags: code-golf, math, division

**NOTE: Some terminology used in this challenge is fake.**

For two integers `n` and `k` both greater than or equal to 2 with `n > k`, `n` is *semidivisible* by `k` if and only if `n/k = r/10` for some integer `r`. However, `n` may not be divisible by `k`. Put more simply, the base 10 representation of `n/k` has exactly one digit after the decimal place. For example, 6 is semidivisible by 4 because 6/4=15/10, but 8 is not semidivisible by 4 because `8 % 4 == 0`.

Your task is to write a program which takes in two integers as input, in any convenient format, and outputs a truthy (respectively falsy) value if the first input is semidivisible by the second, and a falsey (respectively truthy) value otherwise. Standard loopholes are forbidden. You may assume that `n > k` and that both `n` and `k` are at least 2.

Test cases:

```
[8, 4] -> falsey
[8, 5] -> truthy
[9, 5] -> truthy
[7, 3] -> falsey
```

This question is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) therefore shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Do our chosen outputs for truthy & falsey need to be consistent?

Comment: @Shaggy not necessarily

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda n,k:n*10%k==0<n%k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ9sqT8vQQDXb1tbAJk81@395RmZOqoKhFRcnUE7BViEzr6C0REOTi7OgKDOvRCFNAyis@T/aQkfBJJYLRJkCKUsIZa6jYBwLAA)

Checks that \$10n\$ is a multiple of \$k\$, but \$n\$ itself is not.

**24 bytes**

```python
lambda n,k:n%k>>n*10%k*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ9sqTzXbzi5Py9BANVsr7395RmZOqoKhFRcnUE7BViEzr6C0REOTi7OgKDOvRCFNAyis@T/aQkfBJJYLRJkCKUsIZa6jYAykDC0NDAx1FAwNgCAWAA)

The `*n` at the end can't be omitted, say for `n=19001, k=10000`.

Comment: [23 bytes?](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ9vK0C5Py9BANdsmTzX7f3lGZk6qgqEVFydQSsFWITOvoLREQ5OLs6AoM69EIU0DKKz5P9pCR8EklgtEmQIpSwhlrqNgHAsA)

Comment: This is what I was attempting to golf @dingledooper, it should be good if it expands to 1>n*10%k AND n*10%k <n%k as I think

Comment: @dingledooper Yes... Post an answer and I'll give it a bounty.

Comment: @xnor [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220367/88546)

Answer (score 10):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 31 bytes

```r
function(x,y)nchar((x/y)%%1)==3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfoJpZHF@cmpuZklmWWZyZlJMan1SpmmD7P600L7kkMz9Po0KnUjMvOSOxSEOjQr9SU1XVUNPW1vi/mQJWnQomCsoKJUWlqVwWeBSkJeYU41ZhCjPCkpACcxwKjOF2/AcA)

Fractional part (`%%1`) of `x/y` must be 3 characters: so, `0.1`, `0.2` ... `0.9`, but not `0` or `0.3333`.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 23 bytes

Saves 1 byte from [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220283/88546) *(for the [bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18334/88546))*. Notice that the chained comparison forces `n*10%k = 0` and `n%k > 0` to both be true.

```python
lambda n,k:1>n*10%k<n%k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ9vK0C5Py9BANdsmTzX7f3lGZk6qgqEVFydQSsFWITOvoLREQ5OLs6AoM69EIU0DKKz5P9pCR8EklgtEmQIpSwhlrqNgHAsA)

Comment: I'll post the bounty when the question is old enough to allow it

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>12</s> 9 bytes

```apl
3=∘≢∘⍕1|÷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRj20cdMx51LgKRvVMNaw5v//@obypQwkIhTcFE4VHvXAVdO4W0xJziSi6EhClMoqSotCQDJmOJU8YcKGOMYth/AA)

The previous, obvious method.

```apl
'.'=∘⊃¯2↑∘⍕÷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wR1PXXbRx0zHnU1H1pv9KhtIojdO/Xw9v@P@qYCpS0U0hRMFB71zlXQtVNIS8wpruRCSJjCJEqKSksyYDKWOGXMgTLGKIb9BwA)

Comment: It works, but it's not so obvious to me ;)

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I think this is right; I'm quite drunk!

```
*A vV «UvV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=KkEgdlYgq1V2Vg&input=NyAz)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>25</s> <s>24</s></sup> 23 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84844/aztecco)!!!
Thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper) who found and fixed a bug!!!

```c
f(n,k){n=n%k>0>10*n%k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDhaoMwEP7vU1wFQe3JdG3ZitM/Y08xZUiMnWRLixEmE1997mqi1LFwOS73fXeX@1hwYmwcK1ei8HqZSEekYRqFPgXxMH4WtXQ9q7eATi1baLlq3@RrDgn0jwhkR4QH7Yd4TROatkc4TLZDiEKE/Q2PdxfOWl5qJoHRZDoIDZG9F41PnjPBG820s@7lPuuOz3QPNsLte2ebuurcgHudUsuSd1QWxiZ8AlV/83PlzvO9O5Pwl0wM2@3E9kCvP/9ZUicjw4Tn8QoWMyz@hRXBWu11nlN@UeNv4aUhSuXaTonglBCkV@@oTNLqEkEgKFwE2mxUkvDc9B@sYfxh1UdxUmPw9Qs)

Inputs integers \$n\$ and \$k\$ and returns a truthy iff \$10n\$ is divisible by \$k\$ and \$n\$ isn't divisible by \$k\$.

Comment: <1 instead of ==0

Comment: @AZTECCO Nice one - thanks! :D

Comment: This version doesn't work, unfortunately, since `10*n%k` does not have to be non-zero. For example for `7 4` it returns `1`.

Comment: Ah I see why it fails now, the order of precedence is wrong. I think switching it works? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDhaoMwEP7vU1wFQe3JdG3ZitM/Y08xZUiMnWRLixEmE1997mqi1LFwOS73fXeX@1hwYmwcK1ei8HqZSEekYRqFPgXxMH4WtXQ9q7eATi1baLlq3@RrDgn0jwhkR4QH7Yd4TROatkc4TLZDiEKE/Q2PdxfOWl5qJoHRZDoIDZG9F41PnjPBG820s@7lPuuOz3QPNsLte2ebuurcgHudUsuSd1QWxiZ8AlV/83PlzvO9O5Pwl0wM2@3E9kCvP/9ZUicjw4Tn8QoWMyz@hRXBWu11nlN@UeNv4aUhSuXaTonglBCkV@@oTNLqEkEgKFwE2mxUkvDc9B@sYfxh1UdxUmPw9Qs).

Comment: @dingledooper We definitely need testcases like that - nice one, thanks! :D

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
€tḊ10/¹⌉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fG6zhpaSga6eglKqpUez2qKkxt6hc89C2/4@a1pQ83NFlaKB/aOejns7///@bKZhwWSiYclkCsbmCMZBtwmVoYKhgaGAAAA)

Uses a different approach from what I have seen in other answers, could be even shorter if I found a better way to check if a number is in [2,5,10]. (Any golfing language with a single-byte builtin for 10 could probably do it)

#### Explanation

Taking 2 numbers \$a\$ and \$b\$, we compute: $$\frac{lcm(a,b)}{a}$$

This value will be equal to the smallest number you have to multiply \$a\$ by to make it divisible by \$b\$. Since we don't want \$a\$ to be divisible by \$b\$ we'll need this to be greater than 1, and since we want \$10*a\$ to be divisible by \$b\$ we'll need this to be a divisor of 10. In the end we want the result to be one of [2,5,10].

```
€tḊ10/¹⌉
       ⌉    Least common multiplier of the two numbers
     /¹     divided by the first number
€           Find its position in the list: (returns 0 if missing)
  Ḋ10        divisors of ten: [1,2,5,10]
 t           except the first: [2,5,10]
```

Comment: I assume `İ€` doesn't help here?

Comment: @Razetime unfortunately not, numbers like 100 would be a problem

Comment: other golfing languages would have a single byte 10, but a two-byte divisors :P

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 18 bytes

```javascript
n=>k=>n%k>0>10*n%k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i7b1i5PNdvOwM7QQAvI@J@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGmYaGpYaKpaa2gr6@ga6eQlphTXMmFocIUoaKkqLQkA12JJWEl5poaxmj2/AcA)

-2 bytes thanks to [iota](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99986/iota)

-1 byte indirectly from Neil or Noodle9 or dingledooper

Comment: [fails for `[1,7]`](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@18jTydb09bO0EArTzVb0RZI/E/OzyvOz0nVy8lP10jT0NPTizbUMY/V1LRW0NdX0LVTSEvMKa78DwA). You need to check if `n*10%k` is 0.

Comment: @ovs we have to take `n > k` with `k > 1`.

Comment: I didn't read the entire challenge spec before, but this still fails for `[8,7]`

Comment: @ovs oh I get it, I was thinking that `n%k` returns a bool telling whether `n` is divisible by `k` [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@18jTydb09bOKT8/JzUxT8PQQCtPNVtT0RYmAOL9T87PKwZy9XLy0zXSNPT09KItdExiNTWtFfT1FXTtFNISc4orubCpMkVSVVKUUVqCTZklccosdMzR7fwPAA "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online"). I don't know why I had this confusion.

Comment: [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i7b1s7QQCtPNdvGUE0NSP1Pzs8rzs9J1cvJT9dI07DQ1DDR1LRW0NdX0LVTSEvMKa7kwlBhilBRUlRakoGuxJKwEnNNDWM0e/4DAA)

Comment: @AZTECCO no I just forgot to take it of. Nice one @iota!

Comment: [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i7b1s7QQCtPNdvOwAZI/k/OzyvOz0nVy8lP10jTsNDUMNHUtFbQ11fQtVNIS8wpruTCUGGKUFFSVFqSga7EkrASc00NYzR7/gMA) and returns a boolean

Comment: @user81655 that's very clever

Comment: @user81655 fails for e.g. `10, 6`.

Comment: (Best I could do was to port @Noodle9's C answer.)

Comment: Ah, you're right. Sorry @SheikYerbouti

Comment: Thanks @Neil! @user81655 don't worry, it happened to me as well, we need more test cases.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

```hs
n#k=(10*n`mod`k<1)>(n`mod`k<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P08521bD0EArLyE3PyUh28ZQ004Dwf6fm5iZp2CrUFCUmVeiEA1UXBOdp5Mda6MbHW2ho2ASqwOiTIGUJYQy11Ewjo2N/Q8A)

- inspired by @xnor [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220283/84844)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
×⁵ọ¹ȧ%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9EeNWx/u7j2088Ry1f@H2/UfNa35/z862kLHJFYHSJoCSXMwaaljDCQNDQx0zGNjAQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>41</s> <s>40</s> 35 bytes

```
$
0
\d+
$*
^(1+),(?!(\1{10})+$)\1+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4a8SlxCTos31X4XLgAvEUNHiitMw1NbU0bBX1IgxrDY0qNXUVtGMMdRW@f/fQseEy0LHlMsSiM11jAE) Takes inputs in reverse order, but header in link reverses the test suite for convenience. Explanation:

```
$
0
```

Multiply `n` by `10`.

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert `k` and `10n` to unary.

```
^(1+),
```

Match k, then ...

```
(?!(\1{10})+$)
```

... while ensuring `10k` doesn't divide `10n` (i.e `k` does not divide `n`), ...

```
\1+$
```

... ensure `k` divides `10n`.

Comment: Got my answer down to [40 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249412/17216) in Retina.

Comment: @Deadcode Nice, so that means we're tied now ;-)

Comment: Cool. I figured you'd probably be able to get it down by at least 1 byte once the necessity arose. :-)

Comment: @Deadcode It turns out that I was able to get it down by at least 1 byte. Or more accurately, once I'd come up with the alternative approach, I was then able to golf that down further.

Comment: Nicely done, now that's more like it. This of course doesn't mean that yours wins in all regards; mine is still competitive as a pure regex.

Comment: @Deadcode Yes it's interesting how much you can do without being able to compute values larger than your inputs.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

```
3=[#@":@%~|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/jW2jlR2UrBxU62r@a3KlJmfkK6inJeYUVyokJxanFqtDhEwU0hQsIExjINOcC6qypKi0JANVqSlCKYhpqfAfAA)

Looks like I stumbled on almost exactly the same method as the APL answer.

- `[...%~|` The left input `[` floating point divided into `%~` the remainder when the left input is divided into the right input `|`.
- `#@":@` Format that result as a string and take its length.
- `3=` Does that equal 3?  This will only be true for numbers of the form `0.n` where n is an element of the digits `1-9`.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 36 bytes

```powershell
param($n,$k)!((10*$n)%$k)-and($n%$k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPRyVbU1FDw9BASyVPUxXI0U3MSwGKg5j///@3@G8CAA)

Inspired by @xnor method of checking if 10n is multiple of k but n itself not

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqZgq1D9vyCxKDFXQyVPRyVbUyVPVSVbS1FDw9BASyVPE8jR/F/LxaUGVGqhYAKlTcG0JZQ2VzD@DwA "PowerShell – Try It Online") using truthey / falsey values

Answer (score 3):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 15 bytes

```
.~@~%!!@10*@%!&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X6/OoU5VUdHB0EDLQVVR7f9/CwVTAA)

Unfortunately, as GolfScript lacks support for floating-point values, I couldn't use the strategy of looking for the decimal place. The program just checks if n % k is truthy and 10n % k is falsy.

Also of note is that I found it easier to take the input as a string containing two space-separated integers instead of taking it as two integers directly.

```
.~@~                  prepare two sets of n and k
    %!!               check if n % k > 0
       @10*           multiply n by 10
           @%!        check if 10n % k = 0
              &       AND both values
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
function(x,y)!(x*10)%%y&x%%y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfoJpZHF@cmpuZklmWWZyZlJMan1SpmmD7P600L7kkMz9Po0KnUlNRo0LL0EBTVbVSrQJI/DdTwKpNwURBWaGkqDSVywKPgrTEnGLcKkxhRlgSUmCOQ4Ex3A5DSwMDQxyqDA2AAK7yPwA)

Test harness taken from [Dominic's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220284/55372).

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, <s>31</s> <s>29</s> 20 bytes

```
=LEN(MOD(A1/B1,1))=3
```

*-2 bytes thanks to @Dominic van Essen*

*-9 bytes porting [Dominic's Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220281/semidivisibility/220284#220284)*

Previous Answer

```
=MOD(A1,B1)*(MOD(A1*10,B1)=0)
```

Comment: Nice.  I think you can shave-off the ```>0``` because non-zero numeric values are truthy in Excel (try: ```=IF(A1,"TRUTHY","FALSY")```...

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal v2.6.0+](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
ġ/₀KḢc
```

Takes its input as \$k\$ followed by \$n\$.

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLEoS/igoBL4biiYyIsIiIsIjEwXG4xMjM0NTY3ODkxMjM0NTY4OTUiXQ==)

This uses the same algorithm as my [regex answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249412/17216), which is similar to the algorithm used by [Leo's Husk answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220433/17216). It asserts that $${k\over gcd(n,k)} ∈ [2,5,10]$$

It doesn't use floating point, and can thus handle arbitrarily large integers correctly.

```
ġ            Push gcd(n,k)
 /           Pop the above result, and push k divided by it
  ₀K         Push the divisors of 10, i.e. [1, 2, 5, 10]
    Ḣ        Head remove – drop first element, yielding [2, 5, 10]
     c       Is the above quotient contained in the above list?
```

### [Vyxal v2.5.3ω](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/old), 7 bytes

```
ġ/₀Kḣ„c
```

Takes its input as \$k\$ followed by \$n\$.

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C4%A1%2F%E2%82%80K%E1%B8%A3%E2%80%9Ec&inputs=10%0A123456789123456895&header=&footer=) - v2.5.3ω
[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLEoS/igoBL4bij4oCeYyIsIiIsIjEwXG4xMjM0NTY3ODkxMjM0NTY4OTUiXQ==) - latest

The reason I didn't use the `Ḣ` head-remove element in the first place is that I was referring to outdated documentation – my clone of the git repo was pointed at master instead of main.

```
ġ             Push gcd(n,k)
 /            Pop the above result, and push k divided by it
  ₀K          Push the divisors of 10, i.e. [1, 2, 5, 10]
    ḣ         Head extract – split the above, yielding 1 and [2, 5, 10]
     „        Rotate stack left, such that a=the above quotient, and b=[2, 5, 10]
      c       Is a contained in b?
```

## [Vyxal v2.5.3ω](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/old), 7 bytes

```
Ḋ⁰₀*¹Ḋ<
```

Takes its input as \$k\$ followed by \$n\$.

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E1%B8%8A%E2%81%B0%E2%82%80*%C2%B9%E1%B8%8A%3C&inputs=10%0A123456789123456895&header=&footer=) - v2.5.3ω
[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuIrigbDigoAqwrnhuIo8IiwiIiwiMTBcbjEyMzQ1Njc4OTEyMzQ1Njg5NSJd) - latest

This uses the same logic as in [xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220283/17216) and many subsequent answers, which is to assert that \$n≢0\pmod k\ \land\ 10n≡0\pmod k\$.

```
Ḋ             Push 1 if n is divisible by k, 0 otherwise
 ⁰            Push n
  ₀           Push 10
   *          Push n*10, popping both n and 10
    ¹         Push k
     Ḋ        Push 1 if n*10 is divisible by k, 0 otherwise (pop both)
      <       Is the top boolean less than the bottom boolean?
```

### [Vyxal v2.5.3ω](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/old), 7 bytes, 6 elements

```
k≈↵*⁰Ḋ¯
```

Takes its input as \$n\$ followed by \$k\$.

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=k%E2%89%88%E2%86%B5*%E2%81%B0%E1%B8%8A%C2%AF&inputs=123456789123456895%0A10&header=&footer=) - v2.5.3ω
[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJr4omI4oa1KuKBsOG4isKvIiwiIiwiMTIzNDU2Nzg5MTIzNDU2ODk1XG4xMCJd) - latest

```
k≈            Push [0, 1]
  ↵           Raise 10 to the power of the above: [1, 10]
   *          Multiply the above list by n
    ⁰         Push k
     Ḋ        Are the list items divisible by k? (Result is a list)
      ¯       Take deltas (consecutive differences) of the list. Iff the two
              elements of the list were different, this will be truthy.
```

Oddly, the behavior of `¯` was changed. It used to give \$[a[0]-a[1], a[1]-a[2], …]\$ but now gives \$[a[1]-a[0], a[2]-a[1], …]\$. This doesn't change the truthiness of the output, just the sign of the truthy result: `⟨-1⟩` in old, `⟨1⟩` in new.

Comment: Why not use [the latest version of Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLEoS/igoBL4bij4oCeYyIsIiIsIjEwXG4xMjM0NTY3ODkxMjM0NTY4OTUiXQ==)? lyxal.pythonanywhere.com is really outdated

Comment: @Steffan Ah, thanks. I didn't realize there was more than one interpreter link.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
⁼¹⌕⮌Ｉ∕ＮＮ.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMO1sDQxp1jDUEfBLTMvRSMotSy1qDhVwzmxuETDJbMsMyVVwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NHAYULBDoKSnpKQNr6/38LBdP/umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for semidivisble, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
      Ｎ     First input
     ∕      Divided by
       Ｎ    Second input
    Ｉ       Cast to string
   ⮌        Reversed
  ⌕         Index of
        .   Literal `.`
⁼           Equal to
 ¹          Literal 1
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal 2.0.0](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
/Ṫt\.=
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%2F%E1%B9%AAt%5C.%3D&inputs=5%0A8&header=&footer=)

Checks if the second last character is "."

Comment: This crashes when n%k==0, e.g. with the test case `[8, 4]`. Did it work on an earlier version of Vyxal?

Comment: @Deadcode it works fine if you use the [latest version](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIv4bmqdFxcLj0iLCIiLCI1XG44Il0=).

Comment: @Steffan It crashes on a different set of cases in the [latest version](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIv4bmqdFxcLj0iLCIiLCI4XG40Il0=).

Comment: [Here's a 6 byter](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%2F%E1%B9%98%5C.%E1%B8%9F%C4%8B&inputs=5%0A8&header=&footer=) that works in all cases (as long as the numbers aren't too large) using the same basic algorithm. It returns falsey for semidivisible.

Comment: @Steffan P.S. I think an algorithm like this is basically impossible to implement in modern Vyxal, due to its automatic approximation of floats in fractional notation. I couldn't find any way to disable this behavior in the latest version of Vyxal; how about implementing one, perhaps with a flag?

Comment: @Deadcode You can add the `ḋ` flag and it will print as a decimal, but there's no way to stop it from using rationals internally.

Comment: @Steffan Yep, that only affects output. `/SṘ` still reverses the fraction rather than the decimal. But I see now, there is a builtin to do this, `øḋ`, so it is possible to do this challenge using the decimal point algorithm in v2.14.0, but it takes [8 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuIsiLCIiLCIvw7jhuIvhuZhcXC7huJ/EiyIsIiIsIjVcbjgiXQ==).

Comment: Right but it just converts to a string. If Vyxal encounters a decimal, it will immediately convert to rational. It's just how it works.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
&¬%³*10¹%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fq3Fo@aOmxkdtEx61TdL8r3ZojeqhzVqGBod2qv5XSq0oSE0uSU1RyC8tKSgtsVIw1DHQMQRCAwUNMx0TheiSotKSjMpYhbT8nJz8cqDCpEqFkoxUBROF9Myy1DyFktTiEt3kxOLUYs3//6OjTXTMYnWApAWQNIWSlkDSWMc8NhYA)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 13 bytes

```
{>/~y!10 1*x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqtpOv65S0dBAwVCrovY/kAJCAzCuU0hT0FNX0LBQMLG2UDC1tgRicwVjIG1oAGSYaP4HAA)

Uses [@xnor's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220283/98547). `n` is `x`, and `k` is `y`.

- `10 1*x` generate list of 10 times `x`, and `x`
- `y!` mod each of those by `y`
- `~` not them, i.e. check if `y` evenly divides `10*x` and `x`
- `>/` return true iif `y` evenly divides `10*x` but not `x`

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> <s>8</s> <s>8</s> 6 bytes

-2 thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen

```
/`×'.å
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fP@HwdHW9w0v//zflsgAA)

[Try more cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WGZRgr65vb6@k8KhtkoKSfWXCf/2Ew9PV9Q4v/a/zPzraTMckVifaAkqaAklLMGmuYwwkDXUMIaQBlILTBrGxAA)

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f30jj8Ap1vcD//025LAA "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @Lyxal that returns 1 on [8, 4] even though it should be falsely

Comment: Also generally `2(è` can be turned to `¨θ`

Comment: [``/`×'.å`` (**6 bytes**)](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WGZRgr65vb6@k8KhtkoKSfWXCf/2Ew9PV9Q4v/a/zPzraTMckVifaAkqaAklLMGmuYwwkDXUMIaQBlILTBrGxAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Regex (ECMAScript), <s>35</s> 33 bytes

```
^(?=(.+)\1*,\1+$)(\1\B|\1{5})\2?,
```

Takes its input in unary, as the length of two strings of `x`s delimited by a `,` specifying (\$k,n\$).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9BbtswEEX3OgUVNNaMxSikLTmuBdZAgBToJou2u6gFCIeRVVG0QNJNGtunKLLL6XoRl2pSIAs@Dub/j5n5IX9Kt7JN789c39wq221Mq34drTDqnnxW9dVDD/AoPpyPj99hKSBLseJjWvH0HULFq8t9xXfFAavJkh7H54@Y@c0XbxtTA2ZONysFM3qWI5ZOsPJ@3WgFoIVV8lY3RgFiLMxWa9y50agPOQ@DlZe10JnrdeMhoQmWzR3UmVam9utYTPb7xl3LazCil9apTyFV37BviP@F9q3Ag4D91jtv4eTK2o1dkJNUYxkRorRTu44IAslDklnVK@mhxTQMTd90DGLWSb9ag8WSyOA3p20sGBmNCJgxZ3jainAgeR0DcdwJIcmSJH@ef5OELIbiiSSYQjd0v9qtWpAX4aMMSywGLex0OBznNI/mtIjeh3dBp@HnLBR5NKW8iPIBfEJzFvHpwIvZwGI@cML@MXiLGeWziDMewiwKlr8)

This uses a similar algorithm to [Leo's Husk answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220433/17216). We can't directly compute \$lcm(n,k)\$ since it can be larger than both the inputs, so instead we compute \$k/gcd(n,k)\$, which is conveniently equivalent to \$lcm(n,k)/n\$. All that remains is to assert that the result is in \$[2,5,10]\$.

```
^                   # tail = K
(?=
    (x+)\1*,\1+$    # \1 = greatest common factor of K and N
)

# Assert that K == \1*2, \1*5, or \1*10, i.e. that K/\1 == 2, 5, or 10
(                   # \2 = one of the below choices, \1 or \1*5
    \1              # tail -= \1
    \B              # Assert tail > 0; this prevents matching on K == \1
|                   # or
    \1{5}           # tail -= \1*5
)
\2?                 # optionally, tail -= \2; this option must be taken if
                    # \2 == \1, because in that choice, the assertion was made
                    # that K > \1
,                   # Assert tail == 0
```

## Regex (ECMAScript), 33 bytes

```
^(((x+)(\3{4})?)\2?),(?!\1+$)\3+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9NbtswEIX3OgUVJNaMxSikJTuuBdarFOgmi7a7ugUIh5VZUbRA0o0Tx6cousvpchGX6g@QBT8O5r2Hmfkuf0i/droPl77Xd8p1W9uqh5MTVt2TD6q52fcAj@Lt1fj0FQD2OcKqPFRHXOJqskQKy3TF83Nclfn5aXz1iEXYfgxO2waw8EavFczoZYVYe8Hq@402CsAIp@Sd0VYBYirszhg8@NGoj7kAg5XXjTCF740OkNEMa/0NmsIo24RNKiZPT9rfyluwopfOq/cx1XxmXxD/C@1rgUcB@13wwcHZjXNbtyBnucE6IUQZrw4dEQSyfVY41SsZoMU8Ds1fdSxi0cmw3oDDmsjotxdtKhgZjQjYMWd40Yp4IPk3BtK0E0KSJclenn@SjCyG4hfJMIdu6H5yO7Ugf4V3Mi6xGLS40/F4mtMqmdNp8ia@a1rGn7NYVElJ@TSpBvAJrVjCy4HXs4HT@cAJ@8Ponc4onyWc8RhmSbT8Bg)

By an interesting coincidence, there's another method that has the same length. It asserts that both:

- \$k\$ does not divide \$n\$
- At least one member of \$\{k, {k\over 2}, {k\over 5}, {k\over 10}\}\$ is an integer and divides \$n\$ (of course it's redundant to try to assert that for \$k\$, as it contradicts the previous assertion, but it results in a shorter regex)

```
^                    # tail = K
# Divide \3 = K, K/2, K/5, or K/10
(                    # \1 = tail == K
    (                # \2 = \3 or \3*5
        (x+)         # \3 = any positive number satisfying the assertions below
        (\3{4})?     # optionally add \3*4 to \2
    )                # tail -= \2
    \2?              # optionally, tail -= \2
)
,                    # Assert tail == 0;
                     # tail = N
(?!\1+$)             # Assert N is not divisible by K
\3+$                 # Assert N is divisible by \3
```

## Regex (Ruby), 31 bytes

```
^(((x+)\3{4}?)\2?),(?!\1+$)\3+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU9dS8MwFH3vr7gp25Ius7R@vFhCGUx9mzAGvhRLZamUbllJOpyIPvoD/In@kXqXVCd6IeHecw7n3Kt3D8@dBgEL@Sj3TajkE8ymy2moZbFKvKYwRq6Qjjyp9VYb25ZbDQoqBXEYxhexnetfM2AVqFTDmogIRiNgahxHwbAWIrLsBlnm7/1xDRz8iX/4cVIBiDfQVlKV6EEEELKx86GaXWtAhe02N5xOKK/7Fj7fP4BytoEU6FLvJIVLoNfF2kgaIH0Cd4vb@Q2hP079NVyAW1ei9Bjjrj6SauXhS2zT6Eq1veQ7vpWmxXgHEhEf1jB2BxvvcOrhSX0u3hUl4Kz8TPnc4X/8HPjfryyqNfq5ffL8aj7L8@6eMbbnQXb2cv6aBtlpGkxYSrKYDxDjg677Ag)

This is a straight port of the above ECMAScript regex. Ruby allows multiple back-to-back quantifiers in situations where the meaning is unambiguous, so `(\3{4})?` can be done as `\3{4}?` instead. In other regex engines, the `?` in `\3{4}?` would be interpreted as modifying the quantifier to be lazy (non-greedy), even though on a constant quantifier that has no effect.

Note that `(A{N,M})?` *cannot* be changed to `A{N,M}?` in Ruby, because in that case the `?` does act as a lazy modifier to the quantifier.

#### Regex (ECMAScript), <s>171</s> 151 bytes

Just for kicks, let's see if we can port the algorithm from [xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220283/17216) and many subsequent answers, which is to assert that \$n≢0\pmod k\ \land\ 10n≡0\pmod k\$. The challenge here is that we can't directly compute \$10n\$, since regex can't operate on numbers larger than any of the inputs (of course, we could if \$k\ge 10n\$, but in most cases it won't). So we need to emulate the calculation of \$10n\$ modulo \$k\$.

`^(?=(x*),\1*(x*))(?=(?=\2\B(x*))(x*(?=\3\3)|\2\2))(?=((?=\4(x*))x*(?=\3\6)|\4\2))(?=((?=\5(x*))x*(?=\3\8)|\5\2))(?=((?=\7(x*))x*(?=\3\10)|\7\2))\9{2}\b`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBNbtswEIX3OgUdINaMrCii/uxYYA0USIFusmi7q1qAdVhZFUULpNw4sX2KoruerhdxybgBnAUfZ@Z7gxnyB//JzVI3/XBl@uZe6G6tWvF41EyJB/JB1LfbHuCJvbkOjl9hwWAbYFjRwN3o8gWrkurtKd0GLk2rFPe2mJwMrpQ98xdcWJyd4/wVnlmcn@PpK0xjy6eOVze75FB9OwbXTxgN64@DblQNGBnZLAUU4VWGWBoWlw@rRgoAybTg97JRAhBHTG2kxJ0Zj3vbN4Cz0rJmMjK9bAbwQx/L5jvUkRSqHlYjluz3jbnjd6BYz7UR721X/Tn@gvgC2nNALcB@M5hBw8Wt1ms9JxcTiaVHiJBG7DrCCPhbP9KiF3yAFid26OSsohCjjg/LFWgsCbd@ddmOWEzGYwIqsF9x2TL7QPJ/DIxGHWOcLIj/988v4pO5C34THyfQueonvRFzcgLvuF1i7pjd6XA4zsLMm4W5d2PPNEztTWMbZF4a0tzLnNAkzGKPpk6nhdN85jSJn9V68yKkhUdjaptjz1r@AQ)

```
^                      # tail = K
(?=(x*),\1*(x*))       # \1 = K; \2 = N % K
(?=
    (?=
        \2             # tail -= \2
        \B             # Assert 0 < \2 < K
        (x*)           # \3 = tail == K - \2 == also a tool to make tail = \2
    )
    (                  # \4 = (\2 + \2) % K == (N * 2) % K
        x*(?=\3\3)     # \4 = head = \2 - \3
    |                  # if above failed due to K - \2 > \2 then fall back on:
        \2\2           # \4 = \2 + \2
    )
)
(?=((?=\4(x*))x*(?=\3\6 )|\4\2))   # \5 = (\4 + \2) % K == (N * 3) % K
(?=((?=\5(x*))x*(?=\3\8 )|\5\2))   # \7 = (\5 + \2) % K == (N * 4) % K
(?=((?=\7(x*))x*(?=\3\10)|\7\2))   # \9 = (\7 + \2) % K == (N * 5) % K

\9{2}                  # tail = tail - \9*2 == K - \9*2
\b                     # Assert tail==K or tail==0, which is equivalent to
                       # asserting (N * 5 * 2) % K == 0
```

This could be shortened greatly in regex flavors with forward-declared backreferences, but it'd still be much longer than 33 bytes.

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```
\d+
$*
^(?=(.+)\1*,\1+$)(\1\B|\1{5})\2?,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcs7DgIxDATQ3ucIUrKxUCa/DQVaiQtwAWsFEhQ0FCs64OzBofCbKcbb/fV4XvvOns16kZunPjATrXY52r13gokF3jgrkNNH8C5fJ3Hh3htnalzooDdz0kTQkikxCuUBIudASMO5DksbxvBXt6UyKiFAnwPp5Ac)

Comment: I felt sure that there was a golf of that 2, 5, 10 divisibility check, and sure enough you found one.

Comment: @Neil I figured you might have been thinking that :-) At the time I posted it though, I thought I'd exhausted the possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

## APL, 14 bytes

```
{0≠.=⍵|1 10×⍺}
```

Explanations. For example, ⍺ = 3 and ⍵ = 5

```
1 10×⍺ ⍝ Make two-element vector: 3 30
⍵|     ⍝ Remanders of division to 5: 3 0
0≠.=   ⍝ Check if they are zero: 0 1 (no yes)
       ⍝ Then check if answers are different
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 22 bytes

```js
n=>k=>/\..$/.test(n/k)
```

Checks that there is exactly one decimal place after division.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/z9Yu29ZOP0ZPT0VfryS1uEQjTz9b839BUWZeiUaahoWmhommJhcS1xSJa4nKNdfUMNbU/A8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 16 bytes

```
*/(.1&none 1)%%*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfS19Dz1AtLz8vVcFQU1VV67@1QnFipYJ9mkaNSrymQlp@kYKNhYKJnQ6IMgVRlhDKXMHY7j8A)

This is an anonymous function where the asterisks represent the two arguments.  The main expression is `* / X %% *`, which checks that the first argument divided by an expression X is divisible by the second argument.  `X` here is an and-junction of the number `.1`, and the none-junction of the number `1`.  Raku threads the expression over the junction, producing a truthy value if the first argument divided by `.1` is divisble by the second argument, AND the first argument divided by `1` is NOT divisible by the second argument.

The return value is a junction of boolean values, which collapses into a single value in a boolean context.  Fortunately, this challenge did not stipulate that the return value must be one of two distinct values, or I'd have to add a `so` to collapse the junction to a regular boolean, for two more bytes.

Note that I used division instead of multiplication because an extra space would have been required to separate the first function argument from the multiplication operator: `* *(10&none 1)%%*`.  `.1` is a rational number in Raku, not a floating-point number, so there's no danger of floating-point rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 35 bytes

```java
n->k->(n/k+"").matches(".+\\.[^0]")
```

Port of my [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220304/99986).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY1Ba8JAEIXv@RVLTruVTAUrWmxzKt4EwaNaGDcbu8lmd8lOBBF/e7rF2LO@y/DefPOmwhNmVVH3uvGuJVZFDx1pA2VnJWln4WWR@O5gtGTSYAhshdpeEhY1xIGQ4jg5XbAmLvmGWm2P2z3D9hjEjf3Tl4sHajkUf9zsulWFlkgqZ@Vnb7O8znJuX@tRmgpokOSPCjyF0W4H2@/xPhX94r9wcw6kGnAdgY8vyVheAnpvznwugFQg/ibEU/z0Qf79SX428JM7f02u/S8)

## Java, 20 bytes

```java
n->k->n*10%k<1&n%k>0
```

Port of [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220283/99986).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY1BC4JAEIXv/oq9FCq4KBUVmqfoFgQeo8Omq6yuu4s7ChL@dtvQOue7DO/NN29K0hGvzKqR1Uo2gErjcQuM47wVKTApsBtaqn1ylqKUE63RlTDxspDRHGsgYEYnWYZqs7QTaJgo7g9EmkI7E/vRWZoDepmLo8neGpqxlACNUX4ahRdXXizcwF9VUbAWqyr2x/DXkPQaaI1lC1iZH8CFnWOiFO/tg4OBarC3jrOI3/3JHxfy@5nffPnBGsY3)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 20 bytes

```scala
n=>k=>n%k-n*10%k*k>0
```

[Try it in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/uFovZj1ZReWVY1LcySfBvA)

If `n` is divisible by `k` but not `n*10`, `n%k-n*10%k*k` is negative. If the both are divisible by `k`, it's 0. If only `n*10` is divisible by `k`, it's positive. If neither is divisible by `k`, it's still negative, because we're multiplying the second by `k` to make it bigger.

Answer (score 1):

## [Templates Considered Harmful](https://github.com/feresum/tmp-lang), 51 bytes

```
Fun<If<Rem<Mul<I<10>,A<1>>,A<2>>,F,Rem<A<1>,A<2>>>>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nNLchJLEkt/u9YYPPfrTTPxjPNJig118a3NMfG08bQwE7H0cbQDkQaAUk3HZAcSAQiYGf3X4eL09PG0g5Mmdpx2f0HAA)

Implementation of [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220283/66421). Anonymous function that takes 2 arguments.

```
Fun<
    If<Rem<Mul<I<10>,A<1>>,A<2>>,  # if 10n%k > 0
       F,                          # false
       Rem<A<1>,A<2>>>>            # else n%k
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Kustom](https://help.kustom.rocks/s1-general/knowledgebase/top/c2-functions), 30 bytes

this one is really small for a language for making android widgets O.o

```
$tc(cut,gv(n)/gv(k),-2,1)=.$
```

28+2 extra bytes for global names

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
/ṫkt"."
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X//hztXZJUp6Sv//R1vomMb@BwA)

#### Explanation

```
/          Divide n by k
 ṫ         Cast to string
  kt"."    The penultimate character must be "."
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 bytes

```apl
{≠/0=1|q,10×q←⍺÷⍵}
```

Not as clever as this [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220285/92642), but whatcha gonna do... :shrug:

```apl
≠/ ⍝ fold by way of not equals (xor)
  0=1| ⍝ divisibility check
      q,10×q ⍝ concatenate 
           q←⍺÷⍵ ⍝ assignment
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR50L9A1sDWsKdQwNDk8vBAo96t11ePuj3q21//9bKKQpmHCBSFMuSzBpDiSNAQ)

Answer (score 0):

## VBScript, 45 bytes

```
sub f(n,k)
msgbox 10*n mod k<>n mod k
end sub
```

Porting of @xnor's answer a little changed.

Check if 10n is multiple of k but n itself not by checking those conditions aren't equal with `<>`

Answer (score 0):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 37 bytes (29×2=58 codels)

```
TABLiIiIAQJjJjJBDFjJBRLBiIIAQJAMVcRrr
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJx1jsEKwyAQRH8l7HkFNaZVf8V4KKmFQGoDNqfSf-_SrsFS6sE36ww7PmC6nRP4ECQqFzGoA9N8WEeyZUt-55StsPtdFyjN7NtMdfV3i_ltc3_b9q8qJmNA_d6sY0QoaQUPQghAWOYraSXp0JTKBP5yWkpCmPO63ckznR0zhcc8NMqx6rsjPF_CRkux)

As an image:

[image]

This is just rotated to make the ASCII encoding shorter. In ASCII, unminified, without being rotated:

```
tabliiaqjjjbdfjbrlbiiaqjamvcr
    ii   jj   j    i       rr
```

As an image:

[image]

Explanation generated by Bubbler's interpreter:

[image]

So basically input, duplicate, input, duplicate, push top value of stack three values down (producing b,a,a,b), multiply by 10, swap, modulo, logical not, push top value of stack two values down, modulo, multiply, logical not, logical not, output.